# Distance Matrix QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to get a distance matrix though QGIS, I have two different point layers to run the distance matrix and have input and target layers correct, output matrix type is Linear(n*k x 3) Use only the nearest (k) target points.

Once saving the CSV file the results are not correct, for example a input point and target point has a distance of 149.5429 when the measured distance is actually 33.662
see below.

```
Southern Cross  Werribee    149.5428661
Flinders Street Werribee    149.5428661
North Melbourne Werribee    149.5428661
Footscray       Werribee    149.5428661
Sunshine        Werribee    149.5428661
Ginifer         Werribee    149.5428661
```

I've checked that the CRS is correct for both point layers and I am still getting this error.

Can somebody please help me through this.

Comment: What CRS are you using for your layers?

Comment: Do you have any idea why *all* of your distances are apparently the same? That's probably the real hint about the problem, rather than the distance being "wrong".

Comment: Also check that the CRS is the same for your Projection and try disabling 'on-the-fly' CRS (_Project_ > _Project Properties_ > _CRS_)