# Strange distance measurements in distance matrix

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I'm trying to create a distance matrix between two point shapefiles in QGIS 2.6. Both are in WGS84 UTM Zone 30N co-ordinates (and so is the project file), but the distance matrix returns values such as 5673346.938, instead of expected numbers of between 1 and 5km.

I saw a similar thread mentioning disabling 'on the fly projection changes' - I've done this, and no change.
Threads already checked:
[Distance Matrix QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133178/distance-matrix-qgis)

[Unable to obtain linear distance matrix](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137392/unable-to-obtain-linear-distance-matrix)

Here are samples of the two shapefiles I'm using, stripped down to just ID and location.
http://www.datafilehost.com/d/32dc1dc6

http://www.datafilehost.com/d/61fff8f3

Comment: Could you please include the link to this thread so that others don't repeat the same one you already checked? Also, maybe you can upload your point shapefiles to a public file-server so that others using MAC can test this? (I use QGIS 2.6.1 on Windows)

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I've added links to the threads I've checked already. I can't upload the shapefiles as they are composed of data I can't legally share. I guess an alternative would be for me to find a sample dataset to test, and see if I get the same problem?

Comment: Awesome Adam, thanks! Don't worry, I understand about data sensitivity :). If you could test it on a sample dataset then atleast we could know that the problem **may** lie within your QGIS and not in the shapefile.

Comment: As it happens, I couldn't quickly find sample point shapefiles, so I've removed the sensitive parts of the data to make two sample shapefiles, now linked in the question.

Comment: Nice one buddy, hopefully others can now test these and see if they replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I was able to partially solve my issue. It seems QGIS saves points as multipoints.
By performing a multipart to single parts change and using the new shapefile produced, I was able to get appropriate results - some of the time.

For some reason, it still doesn't work ALL of the time, even when using the same shapefile.